# RHEL 7.6 : Unable to install VLC

Tags: rhel7

I am having issues install VLC Player on RHEL 7.6

I get the following error

```
Error: Package: libplacebo-0.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libvulkan.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:vlc-core-3.0.6-17.el7.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libprotobuf-lite.so.8()(64bit)
**********************************************************************
yum can be configured to try to resolve such errors by temporarily enabling
disabled repos and searching for missing dependencies.
To enable this functionality please set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf
**********************************************************************
Error: Package: libplacebo-0.4.0-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libvulkan.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:vlc-core-3.0.6-17.el7.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libprotobuf-lite.so.8()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have tried fixing this for the last 3 days, but not able to fix .
Can you someone help with explanation, So that I can understand better and help others as well?

Answer (score 1):

The missing package is in the RHEL optional channel, which you need to enable on your system.

```
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
```

When using RHEL on AWS, enable it this way instead:

```
yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional
```